# Creating directory with mknod()

Tags: c, directory, mknod

I need to create a directory using `mknod()` (use of `mkdir()` is not allow in my case), I would call the program from a certain directory and introduce the path where the new dir should be created inside the previous one.

Ex: If I'm `/home/user/test/` and inside `test` there is `/level1/`, I want to create the directory `level2` inside `level1`, so I would pass the argument `/level1/level2/`

I have the following code that works when I create a pipe,but when I change the mode to `S_IFDIR`, it doesn't do anything.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int status;
    if ((status  = mknod(argv[1], S_IFDIR,0)) == 1){
        printf("error\n" );
    }
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are running the code on an operating system (e.g. linux) that does not support creating directories with mknod().

Comment: in linux, the man page for mknod says: The file type must be one of S_IFREG, S_IFCHR, S_IFBLK, S_IFIFO, or
       S_IFSOCK to specify a regular file (which will be created empty),
       character special file, block special file, FIFO (named pipe), or
       UNIX domain socket, respectively.  (Zero file type is equivalent to
       type S_IFREG.),   I.E. there is no ability to generate a (sub-)directory   here is the link to that man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html

Comment: @user3629249 I wonder what the rational for disallowing it is. It'd be pretty nice, conceptually, if `mknod` could create all the possible file tree nodes. Perhaps there's a security reason. The ability for filter out directory creations, e.g., with `seccomp`, because they're a separate syscall?

Answer (score 6):

`mknod` is normally used for creating device nodes (special directories).

However,  some OSs do support creating a regular directory with `mknod` (QNX).

Did you check the man page for mknod on the OS you're using? I am quite sure that `S_IFDIR` is a non-portable option for `mknod`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code above.  I bumped into this on an old version of unix and mknod needed the effective id of root in order to create the directory. I suspect if you called perror("") after the failure you will get something about "Not Allowed".