# Whats the difference,speed and implementation, between os.mknod() and open('FILENAME', 'a') in python?

Tags: python

## I want to create an empty file in python.

Currently I am using `open('FILENAME', 'a').close()` but I've seen a lot of people use `os.mknod()`.

I did some research and it seems that `os.mknod()` uses tools from the OS you are using (hence its library name) and that `open()` is the "pythonic" way of creating an empty file.

> What is the difference, in terms of speed and implementation between these two methods?
>
> Would you recommend any other, more reliable or faster method to create an empty file?

Comment: Your equivalence in semantics is wrong. I don’t know where you’ve seen mknod, but it is NOT for creating normal files. It’s for device files. So you are comparing apples to moonpies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you probably want to create *regular files* with `mknod` like this:

```
os.mknod(path, mode=0o600 | stat.S_IFREG)  # it seems that mode argument can be omitted for regular files
```

Well, don't since it's not portable ([Unix only](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mknod)). Stick to `open` when you can (even if `mknod` is probably called behind the scenes on unix when creating a file, the performance difference is very small)

You can check another Q&A ([Creating directory with mknod()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811662/creating-directory-with-mknod)) where the answer hints at the non-portability of `os.mknod`.

Another possible difference (didn't check that point) is that if the file already exists, `mknod` may return an error/exception, while `open` happily opens the file if the permissions allow it.

Don't forget that methods from `os` package are OS dependent. Using them sometimes ties you up with the system you're running on (even if it's safe to assume that `os.remove` and `os.rename` are available, with - of course - implementation differences).

Also note that `open('FILENAME', 'a').close()` does not necessarily create an empty file. If the file exists and the permissions are right, it just does nothing (`a` is for *append*).

- To open with truncation and remain 100% portable, use `open('FILENAME', 'w').close()`
- A slightly faster way is to open in binary without buffering: `open('FILENAME', mode='wb', buffering=0).close()`
- For speed and reduced risks of non-portability: `os.open` is also an option since it's lower-level, and supported on all python environments that provide `open`: `os.close(os.open('FILENAME',os.O_CREAT|os.O_BINARY))`

Comment: Since the OP asked for "fast": It may be worth mentioning `open('FILENAME', mode='wb', buffering=0)` instead of `mode='w'`. For earlier 3.x (I can't remember if that means just 3.0, or 3.0-3.1), and for 2.x on systems with slow C stdio,  `os.open` will be even faster (fast enough for optimized C programs like `dd`), still without any of the problems of abusing `mknod`.

Comment: `os.open`, yes. I'll edit, blatantly copying your good comment.